# Are cyclic products, such as $\prod_{cyc} a(b+c) = abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$, a widely accepted notation?

Tags: notation, products

I know that a cyclic sum of three variables can be shortened like this:
$$ab+bc+ca=\sum_{cyc} ab$$
Is it commonplace to do the same with products? That is, is the following an unambiguous notation?
$$abc(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)=\prod_{cyc} a(b+c)$$

Comment: Unsure.  However, I am fairly sure that the following notation is standard:  $$x_1x_2x_3(x_1 + x_2)(x_2 + x_3)(x_3 + x_1)=\prod_{i,j,k \in \{1,2,3\}, ~i,j,k ~\text{distinct}}  x_i(x_j + x_k).$$  Typically, when I use the above notation, I specifically mention that (for example) this represents the product of $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}~$ different expressions, **rather than** $(3!)$ different expressions.

Comment: I personally have never seen $\prod_{cyc}$ used, but I'd consider it just as unambiguous as $\sum_{cyc}$.